# Slow Boot due to multiple "[sdb] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled"

Tags: boot

My laptop boots slowly.

When I dmesg, I see relatively large gaps in `[sdb] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled` which occured multiple times ... upto 18 times.

The large gaps occur at the end of the log -- from line 773 to line 840.

How should I correct this ?

The log of the major time gaps :

```
[   53.736667] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled
[   53.738782] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed

[   53.738790] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  105.451314] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled

[  105.457428] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed

[  105.457441] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  157.161567] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled

[  157.163680] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed

[  157.163692] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  208.874447] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled

[  208.879553] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed

[  208.879561] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  260.583954] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled

[  260.586106] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed

[  260.586115] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  310.762912] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled

[  310.765037] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed

[  310.765049] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  362.474408] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled

[  362.476550] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed

[  362.476557] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  414.183714] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled

[  414.185953] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed

[  414.185962] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  465.899631] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled

[  465.901740] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed

[  465.901751] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  517.608075] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled

[  517.610399] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed

[  517.610409] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  569.324913] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled

[  569.327129] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed

[  569.327137] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  621.034915] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled

[  621.037042] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed

[  621.037053] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  672.746849] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled

[  672.748936] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed

[  672.748948] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  724.459838] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled

[  724.461952] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed

[  724.461962] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  776.171625] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled

[  776.178816] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed

[  776.178829] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  827.882747] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled

[  827.885001] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed

[  827.885013] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  879.595336] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled

[  879.597520] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed

[  879.597531] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  931.308110] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled

[  931.310316] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed

[  931.310329] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  983.020231] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled

[  983.022431] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed

[  983.022441] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 1034.730703] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled

[ 1034.733599] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
[ 1034.733611] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 1059.368276] cfg80211: Found new beacon on frequency: 2484 MHz (Ch 14) on phy0
[ 1086.443035] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled
[ 1086.445245] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed

[ 1086.445257] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 1138.154555] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Test WP failed, assume Write Enabled

[ 1138.156801] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
[ 1138.156808] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
```

I am using Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

You might have an sd card reader that is configured as sdb. Your system wants to set it up during boot, but can't, as there's no card. Try inserting a card whether it helps (just for diagnosing, not for fixing... ;-)